# Proof of uniqueness: first element of a subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If a subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ has a first element, that element is unique.

This problem frustrates me because I came up with an almost trivial proof, but I feel like it shouldn't be so simple because it is an exercise surrounded by difficult exercises in the textbook.

My attempt:

Suppose the first (least) element is not unique. Then there exist elements $a$ and $b$ such that $a\leq x$ and $b\leq x$ for every $x\in S$. Thus, $a\leq b$ and $b \leq a$, so $a=b$ and the first element is unique.

Is this valid?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks ok to me.  You are (implicitly) using a property of real numbers sometimes called trichotomy: for any real numbers $x,y$, exactly one of the following three statements is true: $x<y$, $x>y$, or $x=y$.

Comment: I see. So it was a simple proof then. Thank you

Comment: @paw88789: Actually, you use the antisymmetry rather than the trichotomy.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I think you can use either one, can't you?

Comment: @paw88789: If "first" means "minimum", then you really don't make any appeals to the trichotomy, and the same argument holds for partial orders as well. If $S$ has a minimum, then it is unique. Of course, the indifference between minimum and minimal uses the trichotomy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you don't need to argue towards contradiction here. It just clutters things and you're not really using that.

Let $s\in S$ be a first element, and $t\in S$. If $t$ is a first element, then $s\leq t$ and $t\leq s$. Therefore by antisymmetry of the relation $\leq$, it follows that $s=t$.

(Note that "first" here is taken as *minimum*, which means that for every $t\in S$, $s\leq t$.)

Comment: Much more concise. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think it's valid. I guess it depends on what first element means. If first element means an element $a$ so that $a\leq x$ for all $x\in S$ then your response is excelent. This type of "first" element is usually called the minimum.

If by first element you mean an element $a$ such that if $x\leq a$ then $x=a$ then the result is also true since in the natural numbers we always have $a<b, a>b$ or $a=b$ for every $a,b\in \mathbb N$ (the tricotomy law).This kind of "first" element is called a minimal element. So the same thing you said is true. In conclusion good job.

however note that in general a subset can have more than one minimal element in a partially ordered set, while there can be at most one minimum element.

Comment: I should have clarified: the chapter was on the well-ordering principle, so this "first element" clearly means the minimum.

Comment: Oh ok, then what you did is good. Asaf's solution tells you how to avoid contradiction. But I think you did a good job.

Comment: Well, I'm not adding new information to the proof given by the OP, just omitting the unnecessary clutter... :-)